# No output when finding most frequent k-mers in Text

Tags: python-2.7

When I execute this, there is no response. Why or what might be causing this problem to occur?

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
#Frequent Words

name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 :
    name = "dataset_2_10.txt"
handle = open(name,"r")
Text = handle.read()
k = raw_input("Enter k:")
k = int(k)

def PatternCount(Text,Pattern):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(Text)-len(Pattern):
        if Text[i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern :
            count = count + 1
        i = i + 1
    return count

FrequentPatterns = list()
i = 0
Count = list()
while i < len(Text)-k:
    Pattern = Text[i:i+k]
    Count.append(PatternCount(Text,Pattern))
    i = i + 1
maxCount = max(Count)
#print maxCount
j = 0
while j < len(Text)-k:
    if Count[j] == maxCount:
        FrequentPatterns.append(Text[j:j+k])
        print Count[j]
        j = j + 1
print FrequentPatterns
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to properly format your code and provide enough information about what you are trying to achieve. What do you expect to happen and what happens instead, etc. Consider re-reading the [how-to-ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ThatAwesomeCoder When editing Python questions please keep in mind, that Python uses syntactically important whitespaces. Your edit added errors to the code. The title referred to "most frequent k-mers", so it was also correct.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get any output, because you run into an infinite loop every time you provide a k larger than one.

This is because in the second while loop you only increment j if the k-mer has been found. But since the condition `if Count[j] == maxCount:` is not always satisfied for k > 1, you do not reach the `j = j + 1` and j stays the same. (You can see that, if you add a print statement to your loop.)

To fix this move the `j = j + 1` from the if block (where it is now) to the loop body, like this:

```
j = 0
while j < len(Text)-k:
    if Count[j] == maxCount:
        FrequentPatterns.append(Text[j:j+k])
        print Count[j]
    j = j + 1
```

Now j is incremented every time, regardless if the k-mer was found or not.

---

That said, in python there is a better way to do this. You can use a for-loop to iterate over all indices like you do now, but without the danger of infinite loops. Consider this:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print i
    i = i + 1

for j in range(10):
    print(j)
```

The second loop yields the same result and is much less prone to failure. You generate a list of the numbers [0, .., 9] with `range(10)` and then use each item from the list.